# Hide exceptions from Kestrel console window

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-logging

I am using Kestrel with .NET Core 2 to serve a Web API application.

I want hide exceptions that occur from displaying in the console window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try built-in [Log filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-filtering) mechanism.

> You can specify a minimum log level for a specific provider and category or for all providers or all categories. Any logs below the minimum level aren't passed to that provider, so they don't get displayed or stored.

It should be`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel` category name for such logs. Filter rule may be registered in code  via `AddFilter` extension method for `ILoggingBuilder`:

```
// using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console;

WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        ...
        logging.AddFilter<ConsoleLoggerProvider>(
                          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel",
                          LogLevel.Critical))
    .Build();
```